# PHP Fatal error install composer on cent os 6.5

Tags: centos, composer-php

I'm trying to install composer on my server centos 6.5 PHP Version 5.6.30

I tried it with this command

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

but I get this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Directive 'safe_mode' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16133)
```

how do I fix? thanks

Comment: The [safe_mode](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode) directive was deprecated on PHP/5.3 and finally removed on PHP/5.4. If you are using it somewhere in your configuration you should get rid of it at once.

Comment: where it might be? in php.ini?

Comment: Certainly, that's the most obvious location. You may also have the `php` command aliased.

Comment: on my php.ini i have   ; Safe Mode
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode
safe_mode = On   I have to put off or comment the line?

Comment: Do you by chance have any other file on that directory, such as [`php.ini.rpmnew`](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/25722/what-are-rpmnew-files/)?

Comment: i have php.ini
php.ini.rpmnew
php.ini.saved_by_psa

Comment: how to solve? help me please,

Answer (score 0):

In Linux distributions that use the RPM package format ([all? some?](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/25722/what-are-rpmnew-files/)) you keep your old configuration files when you upgrade a package so your custom changes don't get lost. The default configuration files for the newer version are saved in the appropriate directories but with a `.rpmnew` suffix. It's your job to review them manually and merge the changes you want into your old file (or completely replace it with the new one).

In your case, you possibly upgraded from an earlier PHP version where the [safe_mode](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode) still existed. Since it's finally gone, your PHP configuration is outdated and triggers the fatal error you've found.

My advice is that you rename your current `php.ini` file, put the the new one in its place and manually reapply the directives you think you need (if any).

Comment: ok, so I have to rename the file in php.ini.rpmnew in php.ini and edit my php.ini file php.ini.old? will it work?

Comment: cp /etc/php.ini /etc/php.ini_backup
mv /etc/php.ini.rpmnew /etc/php.ini right?

Comment: Yes, looks appropriate.